# object with some specific properties typescript

Tags: typescript, object

I have a function that accepts some data and function add some properties and return that parameter object.

this is how I am declaring it

```
async setContext(@Body() data: { [key: string]: any }): Promise<{
        additionalData: { id: string, [key: string]: any },
        context: Context,
        [key: string]: any
    }> {
        data.additionalData.id = this._getId(data.additionalData);
        data.context = this._getContext();
        return data;
}
```

but this is showing

```
Type '{ [key: string]: any; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ [key: string]: any; additionalData: { [key: string]: any; id: string; }; context: Context; }': additionalData, contextts(2739)
```

so I tried

```
async setContext(@Body() data: { additionalData?: any, context?: Context, [key: string]: any }): Promise<{
        additionalData: { id: string, [key: string]: any },
        context: Context,
        [key: string]: any
    }> {
        if (!data.additionalData) {
            data.additionalData = {};
        }
        data.additionalData.id = this._getConversationId(data.additionalData);
        data.context = this._getContext();
        return data;
}
```

but now this is showing

```
Type '{ [key: string]: any; additionalData?: any; context?: Context; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: any; additionalData: { [key: string]: any; id: string; }; context: Context; }'.
  Property 'additionalData' is optional in type '{ [key: string]: any; additionalData?: any; context?: Context; }' but required in type '{ [key: string]: any; additionalData: { [key: string]: any; id: string; }; context: Context; }'.ts(2322)
```

should not this work as I am declaring data as

```
data: { [key: string]: any }
```

to have any unknown properties?

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
showing the problem.
You can use the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) to make such an example

Answer (score 0):

I would define the returned type of the function depending on the type of parameters of the function.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2BAHsKBeKBnYAnASwQHMBuAKHNEigBEBDYegSQUygG8pyop6ATfgWAFE9ADYMmAfgBcUAK4IA1gjgB3BBV4BjRMjRzY+1MG1QA2sogh5uQiQC68pao1byAXwpVw0KfQA8groWIEAtsIAPABKEACOCgR4EPxRAawAfAA0UADkAkIiYpKM9HmZUABknDx8gsKiCBIB8lx1vAT8dvhEZB2W1rY4vU4uKmqa5t5ePvTYIAg6UABmSjrFbNgQwPBIpgAU-GXyGQgAlPIACnhwkdvpZcHAlRx1KcAKeGxvvLwAdIDjkxspQ-vUik0WidauCAYCjmV-oVGiUAnxsFA4AAjABWEA251BA063XyKzgcDyoPBnmJ4L0+zQ8jy2PoeGpdRmnkoB3mix0B3OmFedUZuCg4RA6Kw9HU9GEOB2ewMwAOvz+9AQBHCEhZ-DgxE5vE85x8ukQ2Dg4gg-3EhoOUoCZq85yFpCAA)

---

To use it in your case, just replace `'foo'` and `'bar'` by your functions.

---

```
type Context = string;

type DataIn = { 
  additionalData?: unknown;
  context?: Context;
  [key: string]: unknown;
};

type DataOut = Omit<Required<DataIn>, 'additionalData'> & {
  additionalData: { 
    id: string;
    [key: string]: unknown;
  };
};

async function setContext(data: DataIn): Promise<DataOut> {
  return {
    ...data,

    additionalData: {
      ...(data.additionalData as object),

      id: 'foo',
    },

    context: 'bar',
  };
}

(async() => {
  const myData = await setContext({
    animal: 'dog',
  });

  console.log(myData);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a promise which matches with the function signature:

```
async function setContext(@Body() data: { [key: string]: any }): Promise<{
        additionalData: { id: string, [key: string]: any },
        context: Context,
        [key: string]: any
    }> {
        let map:{ additionalData: { id: string, [key: string]: any }, context: Context, [key: string]: any };
        data.additionalData.id = this._getId(data.additionalData);
        data.context = this._getContext();
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve(map) });
}
```

The type of input parameter `data` is incompatible with the `signature` which is causing a compilation error

Playground link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIxAU2QYU2RwA9kAKAAQCF0ATMcgShjuGWAC4YBvGAbQDWOMNxDIATqggBzALrdgEMDAC%20TbgAUJ6ALapcAHh4AoGOYvngdOqjSZgAGwAi7Lrxio6YydJkAaAWFRbF9ZBRglFVV-M0sLKCJSZG5CCGIyWPiLIREfKXDFZTjzVQA%20XhL4xzwYXWAAB04%20a1t7CCdXDm4%20L3y-QNyQ8QL5IujAxPTk1KTMoLzQ0YiotQBuKss2DgA6VrsMDpc3Ha8YAF4YZAALAx2AfRk8AEk6cm3gPZsDh2OOJg22XMHx2UwyyAuV1uIAeTwIcwoAM2FgkeAQEiwEBwAHcYNo9AYcORyKiQOhHAA3HCBVEAKxwUGQTHOZR4pPJVPI9QaTHUG1UQA)

In short, either your input parameter type needs to be changed or the returning object should be populated locally